# How to display an icon inside input field which got updated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I have input boxes which are mapped with an object.

Looking for a solution if the input got updated or any user typed something in input field and then submit then that input field should display an icon inside it(for example if someone updated the first and last input field than only first and last field should contain the icon(Admin) other input boxes should be as it is.)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Admin from 'icons'
//more imports

export default function InputCom() {
  
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const data = [
    { label: "first", name: "first" },
    { label: "last", name: "last" },
    { label: "phone", name: "phone" },
  ];

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };

const handleClick = () => {
console.log(vlaue)
}
  return (
    <div >
      <Card >
        <div >
          {data.map((item, key) => (
            <div key={key.name} >
              <input
                //icon={Admin}
                label={item.name}
                name={item.name}
                onChange={handleChange}
                placeholder="text"
                value={value}
              />
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </Card>
     <button onClick={handleClick}>submit<button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: what do you mean "the input should display an icon"? Inputs are text fields. If you need an icon, you put some template code that has `{ showIcon ? <span ...> : null }` or something, with your render logic setting that value appropriately.

Comment: I already have css in placed and icon inside my input box but i want if some update the value using input box then only that particular input box should display icon inside it. ` <Input //icon={ <IconAdmin />} id={item.name} label={item.name} name={item.name} onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Placeholder" value={value} /> `

Answer (score 0):

You can create a component called `InputWithIcon` that extends a normal `<input>` tag but also adds the icon. And then pass the optional `icon` prop so that it only renders the icon when it's provided:

```
<InputWithIcon
  icon={!!this.state.value && Admin}
  ...
/>
```

Place the icon on the right side of the input and adjust the styles so that it looks as if the icon is inside the input.

This is the pseudo code:

```
const InputWithIcon = ({ icon, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input {...props} />
      {icon && <img src={icon} />}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Styles:

```
div {
  position: relative;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10;
  top: 10;
}

input {
  padding: 10;
  padding-right: 20;
}
```

Hope this gives you the idea.

Comment: I already have css in placed and icon inside my input box but i want if some update the value using input box then only that particular input box should display icon inside it.

`  <Input
                      //icon={ <IconAdmin />}
                      id={item.name}
                      label={item.name}
                      name={item.name}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                      placeholder="Placeholder"
                      value={value}
                    />`

Comment: That's what I described at the top of my answer. Set the state with the inputted value, and render the icon only if the value is not empty.

Comment: by doing so my Admin icon is reflecting in all the inputs fields, 
and is any way after submitting those values the Admin icon will their after the page got reloaded(only in the updated input field).

Comment: If you want it to persist after submitting those values, you can set the state after submitting. If you want it to work after the page got reloaded, you should save that state globally. Using redux or context API or localStorage or API.